# JavaScript button changes the html input name

Tags: javascript, html

I created a button with JScript that adds textareas (questions) one below another onClick. I'm having a trouble in adjusting a function that will change the name of the textareas depending on the number of question (variable n).

So, for the question 1, I want to have **textarea name="question1" ...**

Is there any other solution? Mine is not working :(

[View code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/1/)

```
<input type="submit" value="ADD" onClick="add();">
<div id="new"></div>
```

**script.js**

```
n=1;
function add() {
if(1==1){
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML += '<div>' + n + '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question[n]" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/></div>';
            n++;
            }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
n=1;
function add() {
    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML += '<div>' + n + '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/></div>';
    n++;

}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/2/

Can make your brain happier and debugging easier by splitting up long concatenated strings.

```
var n=1,
    container,
    start, middle, end, out;

function add() {
    container = document.getElementById('questions');

    start = '<div>' + n + '. Question: <br/>';
    middle = '<textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4" cols="50">';
    end = '</textarea><br/></div>';
    out = start + middle + end;             

    container.innerHTML += out;

    n++;

}
```

Alternate fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5FJ4a/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML += '<div>' + n + '. Question: <br/><textarea name="question'+n+'" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br/></div>';
```